# Is this possible in C# to ensure compile time that method/class have given signature

Tags: c#, methods, custom-attributes

Is this possible in C# to ensure that method/class have given signature.

For example I want to ensure that some method is public and static.

When isn't I want to this method red underlined.

I need it because I'm using this with component test runner app which uses reflection and expects public static bool methods from dlls. I want to force programmers to write *public static bools* component test methods. Is this a possibility to force them compile time? Or maybe force them build time by adding another simple app that checks it by reflection during post build event?

Is this possible? Maybe by method attributes? By reflection? But how?

Comment: Not sure at about the underline, but you could probably test this with Unit Tests. You should provide more details on exactly what you are doing for a more helpful answer

Comment: Type the given signature in the method's declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to query custom Attributes in C# during compile time ( not run-time )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753255/is-it-possible-to-query-custom-attributes-in-c-sharp-during-compile-time-not-r)

Comment: Smells like a design problem to me. Perhaps you should take advantage of c# features by replacing your `public static bool` requirement with an interface - `public interface ITestableComponent { bool GetComponent() }`. Now inject some factory instances at runtime (through some mechanism, many exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change/extend the C# compiler to achieve what you want here. However, there is a Microsoft project called Roslyn which exposes a public API for implementing your own extensions to the C# compiling pipeline.

Using Roslyn's structures, it should be easy to traverse your source code syntax trees looking for methods that are not public/static. Once you find them, you could generate a *code issue* reporting the problem; those issues are shown both in the code editor (wavy underline) and in the Errors List panel. From [Roslyn's official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769.aspx):

> The code issue provider makes it easy to surface an error or suggestion to the user as a wavy underline in the editor or appear in the Error List window.

Look around for [examples](https://github.com/filipw/Roslyn.WebApi.IssueExample/blob/master/WebApi.CodeIssue/CodeIssueProvider.cs) of CodeIssueProviders; it could be useful for what you need to do.